# django forms: only customize the labels

Tags: django, django-forms

Is there a way to only customize the label of form fields without specifying the field type?

For example, I have the following model for a user's privileges on handling documents:

```
class Privilege(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    privCreate = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    privEdit = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    privDelete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    ...
```

And I have the following form:

```
class PrivilegeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    privCreate = forms.BooleanField(label='Create a document')
    privEdit = forms.BooleanField(label='Edit a document')
    privDelete = forms.BooleanField(label='Delete a document')
    ...

    class Meta:
        model = Privilege
        fields = ('privCreate', 'privEdit', 'privDelete', ...)
```

There are a lot of fields, and this seems to violate DRY. How can I only customize the labels without specifying `forms.BooleanField` if they are the same as those in the models?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the labels in the `__init__()` using [`.fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#accessing-the-fields-from-the-form):

```
class PrivilegeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PrivilegeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['privCreate'].label = 'Create a document'
        ...
```